# How to download multiple csv files into zip using downloadHandler in Shiny R

Tags: r, csv, shiny, zip

I am new to Shiny, and I've read through MANY questions asking similar, but the solutions I've tried aren't working for me.
I'm trying to download multiple csv files (of data processed in the Shiny app) and zip them up. I'm using `downloadHandler` to get around permissions/folders on various machines of colleagues who will use the dashboard.

Can anyone PLEASE tell me how to get around this? The error I am constantly getting is:

> Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
> cannot open file 'maldiprocres_*genericname*.csv': No such file or directory
> Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection

I have read everywhere that this can be related to write permission in the temporary folder in Shiny. Is this true? How do I make this possible to write to this temporary folder? For information, I'm working in R on a Mac.

I also realise that the loop isn't the most efficient, but allowed a lot of checks in the script - the data (s is list of unprocessed data) is processed and prints out when required and the filenames are correct, I'm just unable to download the processed csv files/zipped folder.

Thanks for your help.

```
#server
datasetInput <- reactive({
                switch(input$dtset,
                       "peaks" = detectedPeaks(),
                       "centroided" = baselineCorrectedSpectra())
        })

    
         
output$downloadZip <- downloadHandler(
   filename = function(){
     paste0("maldiprocresults",".zip")
   },
   content = function(con){
    tmpdir <- tempdir()
    setwd(tempdir()) 
    a=getwd()
    files <- c()
 
     for (i in 1:length(s)){
    x<-as.matrix(datasetInput()[[i]])
     y<-metaData(s[[i]])
     e<-y$file
     z<-gsub((paste(a,"/MALDIquantForeign_uncompress/", sep="")),"",e)
     f<-(paste("maldiprocres", z, sep="_" ))
     print(f)
    if(input$downloadType == ".csv")
    write.csv(x,f)
    else write.table(x,f)
    files<-c(x,files)
    
}       
    zip(zipfile=con, files=files)
     
  }
  ,
   contentType = "application/zip"
 )
```